# Fetch in a Web Worker using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, web-worker

I have a React page that asks for a user input for some info and returns an array of JSON objects from an API.

The query can return a large result causing in the page to freeze on loading the fetch, so I wanted to use a web worker to separate the threads and add a loading wheel to allow the user to know the site hasn't crashed.

I currently have my web worker with this code:

## **Worker Code**

```
const self = this;

export default () => {
    self.addEventListener('message', e => {
        if (!e) return;
        let query = e.data;
        let res = null;

        fetch(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/schedule?startDate=${query}&endDate=${query}`)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(_ref) {
            postMessage(_ref);
        });
    });
};
```

This is just an example API, but the real API result would be much larger and take a longer time to load.

I am also using `function(_ref)` instead of `({ data }) =>` because when processed through babel, `({ data }) =>` would be turned into `_ref.data` when there is no data accessor through ref, and `_ref` works at returning the array.

I have my code implemented in a web worker class like such:

## **Worker Constructor**

```
export default class WebWorker {
    constructor(worker) {
        const code = worker.toString();
        const blob = new Blob(['(' + code + ')()'], { type: 'text/javascript' });
        return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    }
}
```

I call the webworker in another class as such:

## **Web Worker Creation**

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.worker = new WebWorker(worker);
}

getInfo = () => {
    this.worker.postMessage(this.state.query);

    this.setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        open: true
    }), () => {
        this.worker.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
            const res = event.data;
            this.setState({
                results: res,
                open: false
            });
        });
    });
}
```

The issue I have been running into is when I attempt calling it like I am, the web worker doesn't seem to be processing on another thread. The page still freezes even though the web worker is getting the data, as it still sets the state correctly after freezing.

I am new to web workers so is there something that I am missing that would allow it to work or would there be a different way of using a web worker with a fetch?

Comment: You might be experiencing the cost of serializing/deserializing the JSON data if there's a lot of it, since that's a CPU-bound operation.

Comment: (sadly shared array buffers are only available to Chrome. https://caniuse.com/#feat=sharedarraybuffer)

Comment: Any chance you're using Create React App for this? CRA has known issues when using web workers.

Comment: Yes, I am using Create React App

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your page is becoming unresponsive, that's an indicator that the main processing thread is being impacted by CPU-bound operations. I/O-bound operations, like fetching from a URL, would not impact your page's responsiveness, except for a bit of parsing overhead from the response. Therefore, the best usage of workers is to do CPU-intensive operations on a different thread. You gain very little (if anything) performance-wise moving I/O operations to workers.

Most likely, your rendering logic or data processing is what's causing things to hang, not the network request processing.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to identify what the problem is. The response from the API is probably fine, but if you're doing "stuff" to tens of thousands of objects - looping, sorting, mapping, etc - (or rendering thousands of elements) then your page performance is likely to suffer significantly.

Something as simple as pagination might be the answer to everything.

Comment: The issue with the doing "stuff" is the fetch should take around 5 seconds, right when I click on load, the page becomes unresponsive for about 6 seconds, I set breakpoints in the console to see where the code was and see if maybe it was all a rendering issue but the breakpoints were hit at the addEventListener as the page was unresponsive

Comment: Then maybe you've got another problem entirely. Just a cursory glance at your code - its potentially scary that you're adding an event listener to your worker after every setState in getInfo - are you calling getInfo more than once? If so, then you're adding an event listener more than once.

Comment: I do have it tied to a button, it calls the function when the user entered the info needed for the query. Besides that button it is nowhere else.

Comment: That'll bite you later if it hasn't already. You don't want to add a listener every time, you only want to add a listener once (otherwise multiple queries will cause multiple event listeners to get added which means after every individual query your listener callback will get fired multiple times, not just once like you intend). This is separate from your current issue, however.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the tip though, I'll rework that so only one instance of it exists.